# Right way to set abstract class variable value

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

I have c`amera script` class that do culling task and it contains these variables and an event :

```
    protected float CullDetailSmall = 25.0f;
    protected float CullDetailMedium = 80.0f;
    protected float CullDetailLarge = 130.0f;
    protected float CullDetailExtraLarge = 250.0f;
    protected float CullDetailXExtraLarge = 450.0f;
    protected float CullDetailXXExtaLarge = 650.0f;

public virtual void Awake(){
//culling apply logic using above variable values
}
```

The `camera script` class is the base class for `CamFly` and `CamWalk`. Now i want to change the base class `camera script` variable values, so I make this function in each class (`CamFly` and `CamWalk`)

```
public void SetCullingValues(int cullDetailSmall
                                , int cullDetailMedium
                                , int cullDetailLarge
                                , int cullDetailExtraLarge
                                , int cullDetailXExtraLarge
                                , int cullDetailXXExtaLarge
                                , int CullFloor
        )
    {
        base.CullDetailSmall = cullDetailSmall;
        base.CullDetailMedium = cullDetailMedium;
        base.CullDetailLarge = cullDetailLarge;
        base.CullDetailExtraLarge = cullDetailExtraLarge;
        base.CullDetailXExtraLarge = cullDetailXExtraLarge;
        base.CullDetailXXExtaLarge = cullDetailXXExtaLarge;
        base.CullFloor = CullFloor;

        base.Awake();
    }
```

It is working fine and doing what i want but its certainly not a good piece of code. I am amzed that how can i do it correctly?? Remember

1. i am calling above function under some conditions, like if some
   condition are matched then execute above function and change base
   class variable.
2. second i want to this for both inherited members.

Comment: I don´t understand your problem. "certainly not a good piece of code" What makes you think so?

Comment: Other than the fact that the `base` identifier is redundant, I don't see any problem with this code. Why do you think it's bad?

Comment: When i want same functionality in both classes then it should not be redundant. You can see two methods two redundant codes.

Comment: Why not inplement `SetCullingValues` in the base class?

Comment: `Awake()` is not an "event" but a message that gets called by Unity. So you shouldn't need to call it from another method. You should name the method properly and only use it in `Awake` ... would be cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Please check the next link from Microsoft with relevant abstract class documentation and best practices.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract

An abstract class is used as a base template for derived classes. It is used to enforce a design rule.

```
abstract class YourClass
{
    public int a;
    public abstract void A();
}

class Example : YourClass
{
    public override void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Example.A");
        base.a++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan what José is trying to state here correctly is that in your case there is actually no need of/reference to using `abstract` at all. `virtual` can also be used in non-abstract classes.

Answer (score 0):

> have `Camera` script class that do culling task and it contains these variables and an event

I see no event, I see a void returning virtual method named `Awake`.

> It is working fine and doing what i want but its certainly not a good piece of code

What makes you think that? Yes, its improvable but I've seen far worse.

> I am amzed that how can i do it correctly

Yeah, that happens to all of use sometimes...

My two cents of advice:

1. In general, do not expose fields directly. If the fields are subject to modification, use read/write properties. This way you can always ensure that the state of your base class remains consistent.
2. Name methods appropiately so the name conveys what the method does. `SetCullingValues` does not make it clear that the method will also call `Awake`. Either call it `SetCullingValuesAndAwake` or do not call `Awake`.
3. Why is `SetCullingValues` even declared in the derived types? Declare it in the base type.

*1* and *3* assumes you have access to `Camera`. If you don't then there is not much you can do to improve what you already have.

Comment: `Awake` is an event. I can't get camera script directly it is serve as base class for fly and walk cam.